# Reset cache by especific query or mutation

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching, graphql, react-apollo

I want to use the client of react-apollo to reset part of the cache from a key or query, not clean the entirely cache using the client.resetStore().

Example:

```
import { withApollo } from "react-apollo";
import { compose } from "recompose";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";

const cleanEspecificCache = ({ client }) => () =>{
  // What i do here?
}

const enhance = compose(
 withApollo,
 withHandlers({cleanEspecificCache})
)

export default enhance(MyComponent);
```

What i do to make it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Partial Apollo Cache clearing is not supported at the moment as per this issue:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/4

You can use `fechPolicy: 'network-only'` to not cache specific query at all:

```
const enhance = compose(
  graphql(
    gql`{
      food {
        id
        name
      }
    }`,
    {
      options: { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' },
    }
  ),
  ...
);

export default enhance(MyComponent);
```

If you want to go far down into rabbit hole and have a solution now, you can try https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-cache-router
it lets split your cache into two caches or more and then you can reset these caches individually:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import ApolloCacheRouter from 'apollo-cache-router';
import { hasDirectives } from 'apollo-utilities';

const generalCache = new InMemoryCache();
const specialCache = new InMemoryCache();
const cache = ApolloCacheRouter.override(
  ApolloCacheRouter.route([generalCache, specialCache], document => {
    if (hasDirectives(['special'], document)) {
      // Pass all queries marked with @special into specialCache
      return [specialCache];
    } else {
      // Pass all the other queries to generalCache
      return [generalCache];
    }
  })
);
```

And whenever you want to reset specialCache call `specialCache.reset()` in the code.